# Become a participant on github pull request

Tags: github

Is there a way for me to "follow" a pull request on github. I want to be notified if anyone comments or updates the pull request. I believe this is done automatically when I become a participant by commenting on the pull request. But that doesn't seem like a good option in this case because I don't have anything useful to say at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "watch thread" button right at the bottom of every issue page.

Comment: I missed that all the way at the bottom, Thanks.